# Can i increase performance of adobe photoshop if i use Graphic card which are mainly built for Games?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, adobe-photoshop, graphics-card

I use photoshop for to make 2d designs , do not use photoshop 3D functionality. If answer is yes then please suggest me which budget card can increase the performance of Adobe photoshop.

Would it be better to buy PC or Laptop with graphic card instead integrated graphics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother unless you are looking to drive a very large monitor - though most integrated cards go up to high resolutions anyway.

Photoshop will be more taxing on your CPU rather than GPU - I'd spend as much on the processor as possible at the expense of the graphics card.

Comment: see solution 9 on this page http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/331/331412.html

Comment: @Jitendra those are *possible* solutions, not *definite* ones. As Rich mentioned, PS is more CPU bound than GPU. You need to provide detailed information( current system specs, OS used etc)  while posting a question to avoid speculative answers.

Comment: Yeah, but all modern cards have more than that anyway - if yours doesn't, then seems you need that minimum.

Comment: @but integrated graphics share memory with with PC's own memory. so would it be better to opt a external graphics with seperate graphic RAM

Comment: Again, depends on other variables, if you have enough RAM anyway, then it's less of a concern. I'd say it's only worth getting a "proper" card if: less than 1GB RAM, integrated graphics have less than 128MB memory.

Answer (score 1):

CS4 includes some GPU accelerated features, but most of it is UI level. It really depends on whether your workflow involves things that CS4 accelerates or not.

You can find a rundown of accelerated features at Adobe's website [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html#features).